# Linear regression ML denotations

Tags: statistics, machine-learning, regression, linear-regression

Could somebody explain what does it mean this denotation:
$$\min_w ||Xw - y||^2_2$$

P.S. Linear regression is described this way in Machine Learning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a matrix $X$ choose $w$ such that $Xw$ is close to $y$ in the usual Euclidean distance sense.